# unable to get the query string parameter in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am unable to get the querystring parameter from url in asp.net

url is:[here](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=profile%20email&state=%2Fprofile&redirect_uri=http://localhost:14772/WebForm2.aspx&response_type=code&client_id=41866849709-lobbqne5v4asm7dn2fu1v8lubm6pc7e7.apps.googleusercontent.com&approval_prompt=force)

My code is

```
    string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
    string clientid = Request.QueryString["client_id"];
```

i am getting code parameter but client_id is null. wt i am doing wrong here.

Comment: they are assign the value to response_type in code.so code=response_type

Comment: didn't you get it backwards..? i mean, `key=value`. `...WebForm2.aspx&response_type=code&client...` it's clearly `response_type=code` speaking things generally, your `locahost:14772` is the value of `redirect_uri` so taking it's query string will be a bit tricky.

Comment: hi @BagusTesa no,it is dynmically generated url formate

Comment: code is a value in this url, not a key

Comment: You are using this code `Request.QueryString["code"]` in `WebForm2.aspx` right?

Comment: yes i am doing same

Comment: @GOPALYADAV : If you are using `Request.QueryString["code"]` in `WebForm2.aspx`, then you will be able to get the `Query String` values of `WebForm2.aspx` page only.

Answer (score 0):

```
you are use like,

 string code = Request.QueryString["response_type"];
    string clientid = Request.QueryString["client_id"];
```

you are mistake in `string code = Request.QueryString["response_type"];`
check with this please.

Comment: what it says? returning null ah?

Answer (score 0):

The redirection url is not proper encoded hence during redirection from google the query string parameter after first `&` in `redirect_uri` will be ignored (redirect_uri should not contain `&` as it is you have to keep it in encoded form `%26`).

The initial url is (contain 'client_id'):

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=profile%20email&state=%2Fprofile&redirect_uri=http://localhost:14772/WebForm2.aspx&response_type=code&`client_id`=41866849709-lobbqne5v4asm7dn2fu1v8lubm6pc7e7.apps.googleusercontent.com&approval_prompt=force

But after redirected by google its not have Client_Id.

> http://localhost:14772/WebForm2.aspx?state=/profile&code=4/gh9Yl3D5Nn220V3nU8d8E5vzC4SmEP6JncnGa6MrgSs#

The issue is `redirect_uri` content is not encoded correctly. Please configur correctly. It should look like:

> http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A14772%2FWebForm2.aspx%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3D41866849709-lobbqne5v4asm7dn2fu1v8lubm6pc7e7.apps.googleusercontent.com%26approval_prompt%3Dforce